# Vertical alignment in grid of images

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, grids

I'm trying to create a grid of images, with two titles and a caption/text (like in the attached image) on the left side for each row (without the word "Figure"), such that the left text would be in **the center**.

Following is the current code. I haven't managed to make the text appear on center, and if I did, using floatrow, I couldn't get rid of the "Figure" word, or put up titles.

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\par%
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
& RGB & NIR\\
(a) & \includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{whatever.jpg} & \includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{whatever.jpg}\\
(b) & \includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{whatever.jpg} & \includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{whatever.jpg}\\
(c) & \includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{whatever.jpg} & \includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{whatever.jpg}\\
(d) & \includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{whatever.jpg} & \includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{whatever.jpg}\\
\end{tabular}
\caption{some caption}.}%
\label{fig:fig1}%
\end{figure}
```

[image]

EDIT:
It would be best if I could refer to each row separately as if they were figures.

Comment: have alook at the answer below -- using the `multirow` package in the preamble the caption can be centered -- fine tuning can be done by using 9.3 or 9.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
    & RGB & NIR\\
    \multirow{-9.4}{*}{(a)} & \includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{whatever.jpg} & \includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{whatever.jpg}\\
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Thanks, and if I want to reference row (a), how can it be achieved?